# How to export a variable in javascript?

Tags: javascript, es6-modules

I want to export a variable called `recettesFromIngredients` from `search-box.js`  to `ingredients-logic.js`.

So to be more precise `recettesFromIngredients` is a variable with an empty array at first.

But then I fill this empty array here:

```
function ingredients(enteredValue) {
    for (let i = 0; i < recettes.length; i ++) {
        for (let d = 0; d < recettes[i].ingredients.length; d++) {
            if ( recettes[i].ingredients[d].ingredient.toLocaleLowerCase().includes(enteredValue)) {

                recettesFromIngredients.push(recettes[i]); // <-----------

            };
        };
    };
};
```

So what I am trying to do is: once I fill this array I want to export it.

This is what I tried to do

```
export {recettesFromIngredients} // at the bottom of the file after the every function is called
```

In the console I don't have any error the export/import seems to be ok but when I console log this Var in the imported file I got an empty array while in the export file the array is filled as wanted!

What could be the problem that I am getting an empty array in `ingredients-logic.js`? Should I export from another position in the file or in another way?

Comment: Are you calling the function before console logging? Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Hi @EliasSoares, Yes the function is called befor the console log and I will try to optimise my question!
Thank you

Comment: "*But then I fill this empty array*" - please also show the code that is doing that, as well as the code doing the import and using the array. We need a [mcve] to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don’t you try to export the function instead? Then you can call the function in another file , the function will return the filled array.
You have to return the array in the function call  as well.
Your code should look like :

```
export default function ingredients(enteredValue) {
let recettesFromIngredients = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < recettes.length; i ++) {
        for (let d = 0; d < recettes[i].ingredients.length; d++) {
            if ( recettes[i].ingredients[d].ingredient.toLocaleLowerCase().includes(enteredValue)) {

                recettesFromIngredients.push(recettes[i]); // <-----------

            };
        };
    };
return recettesFromIngredients 
};
```

import the function in another file , then
call the function

```
const x= ingredients(enteredValue)
```

now const x has the array

Comment: Hi Omle, i will try to export a function but I'am interested in knowing if exporting a var i such a way is possible or not at all!
Thank you

Comment: It is a bad practice . Usually when you export a variable only when you use it as a constant in another file (configurations , etc..).
When you export a function you can then reuse it in other places in your code .

Comment: I added the fixed code above . try to play with it .
Don't forget to mark the V next to the answer please

Comment: Also look for State Management  , it will answer some questions about passing creating and updating object that stay "alive" while your app runs.